# Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

Спустя час(,) нас окружили немцы

Comment: Домашнее задание? Предложите вариант ответа.

Comment: просто ответить не судьба?

Comment: Не судьба. Мы не делаем домашнюю работу, может только указать на ошибки, если предложите свой вариант. А то потом собственное имя без ошибок написать не можете.

Comment: С чего вы взяли, что это домашняя работа? Это обычный вопрос, такой же как другие здесь! Для чего этот сайт? Не для того ли, чтобы задавать вопросы и получать на них ответы? И по какому такому праву, вы меня оскорбляете? Что мол я двух слов связать не смогу. Вы меня знаете что ли лично? Или умник такой? Где блин модераторы вообще. Если бы у меня был свой, однозначный вариант ответа, наверное здесь бы не было этого вопроса.

Comment: Fuchoin Kazuki - модератор.

Comment: Ну просто замечательно, как тут "обходительно и вежливо относятся к новым пользователям". Вместо того, чтоб сказать есть запятая или нет, оскорбили, школотой назвали, что двух слов связать не могу, ещё и забанят наверняка.

Comment: Возможно...А зачем вы в вопросах, на которые получили ответ, удалили или изменили предложения?  Получились ответы без вопросов.

Comment: Значит так. Модератор - я. Ваш вопрос был принят за домашнее задание, потому что задан именно в той форме, в которой плохо воспитанные детишки пишут свои задания: ни "пожалуйста-спасибо", никаких просьб помочь. Просто, переписано задание - отвечайте, холопы.  
Так вот, уважаемый Миф, поучитесь вежливости, тогда Ваши вопросы и будут путать со школьными заданиями.

Answer (score 4):

В обороте "спустя час" слово "спустя" только формально может быть отнесено к деепричастиям. На самом же деле это слово со стертым лексическим значением и легко может быть заменено предлогом "через" (через час), поэтому запятая здесь не нужна

Answer (score 1):

Это не деепричастие, а предлог, поэтому запятая не нужна. Из Ожегова: СПУСТЯ  что,  предлог с вин.  п.  По прошествии чего-н.,  по  истечении какого-н. времени. Узнал с. год. Приехал с. неделю.

Answer (score 1):

А разве деепричастный оборот не выделяется запятыми даже в начале предложения? Выделяется. Как уже ответили, здесь деепричастный оборот ни при чем.

Answer (score 0):

А ответ на вопрос такой: запятая тут не нужна, потому что деепричастный оборот стоит в начале предложения.

Answer (score 0):

Запятая не нужна. потому что деепричастный оборот в начале предложения.